# How to give a fixed size to image in magnific-popup pluggin

Tags: magnific-popup

I am using magnific-popup pluggin to display some image links in my application. It displays all the images with their actual size. However, I want to display those images with my custom width and height.. How can I do that.. Is there option to give size of content in the magnific-popup during initialization..? Do any one have an idea..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It can be done by changing the respective class's css properties manually. But, that is also fixed for all images.

Thanks.